# bitwise operation left shift in msvc is diffrent from linux gcc?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, bitwise-operators

On Linux using GCC, `1UL<<44` is `0x100000000000`

But on Windows using MSVC, `1UL<<44` is `0`

I am so confused.

Does this show that on Windows a left shift can not shift more than 32 bits?

Comment: On Windows `unsigned long` has 4 bytes, on both 32/64 bits mode. Maybe try `1ULL << 44`. On [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019) you can check `long` range.

Comment: Types `long` and `unsigned long` are not guarantee to be bigger than 32 bits.  Evidently under Windows they *are* 32 bits, so yes, that limits the extent to which you can shift them left.  It looks like your Linux machine, on the other hand, is implementing longer long types, that can manipulate 44-bit values like 0x100000000000.

Comment: @rafix07 thanks very much,ULL solved this problem

Answer (score 2):

In Windows `unsigned long`s are 32 bits wide. This is due to the unfortunate APIs always expecting unsigned longs to be synonymous with 32 bits, (4 bytes) whereas in Unixen having unsigned longs were equally incorrectly often assumed to be of suitable size for storing a pointer. Hence in Unixen it made sense to use 64 bits unsigned longs and in Windows there is no choice but to keep them 32 bits.

Of course it would have always be correct to just use `uint32_t` and `uintptr_t` respectively for these, but lots of code was written before those were standardized.

---

Notice that the standard says that the behaviour is undefined if the shift amount is negative,, or greater than **or equal** to the width of shifted type so on Windows `1UL << 32` has undefined behaviour. This is because there are hardware that zero the target if a wide shift happens, hardware that aborts and hardware that only consider the shifts modulo 32, i.e. in this case executing `1UL << 0` which of course equals 1. So since this operation makes no sense in any portable program some  C compilers can happily assume that they never happen.

Comment: M.m O_o `errno == ENOCOFFE`